# Модальное окно vuetify и vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuetify

Имеется Dialog (модальное окно), которое открывается по клику на кнопку. У данного модального окна  :value="modalState" ,   modalState - это вычисляемое свойство для геттера vuex, который, соответственно, возвращает true/false. К чему можно привязаться, чтобы сообщить стору, что окно закрыто?  По факту закрывается модальное окно по теневой области и становится display: none. Слушать клик по теневой области нельзя, поскольку это псевдоэлемент :before. После того как окно закрылось,  значение  не изменяется и остается равным true, поэтому повторный клик по кнопке модальное окно не открывает.
Другими словами, к чему можно привязать метод closeModal() с соответствующей мутацией?

```
<v-dialog :value="modalState">
// Content...
</v-dialog>


<script>
  export default {
    methods: {

        closeModal() {
            this.$store.commit('closeModal');
        }
    },
    computed: {
        modalState() {
            return this.$store.getters.modal;
        }
    }
  }
</script>


//Store vuex
export default {
    state: {
        isModalOpened: false
    },
    mutations: {
        openModal(state) {
            state.isModalOpened = true;
        },
        closeModal(state) {
            state.isModalOpened = false;
        }
    },
    getters: {
        modal(state) {
            return state.isModalOpened
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте как-то так:

```
<v-dialog :value="modalState" v-on:input="closeModal($event)">
// Content...
</v-dialog>

<script>
  export default {
    methods: {

        closeModal(is) {
           if(!is) this.$store.commit('closeModal');
        }
    },
    computed: {
        modalState() {
            return this.$store.getters.modal;
        }
    }
  }
</script>
```